# Treenode data structure explanation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

In the following program,

what does this mean `left.parent = this;` I know it says make parent of left child to be '`this`' but what exactly is `this`. this refers to current instance method right? but can anyone explain a bit better.

```
public class TreeNode {
    public int data;      
    public TreeNode left;    
    public TreeNode right; 
    public TreeNode root;
    private int size = 0;

    public TreeNode(int d) {
        data = d;
        size = 1;
    }

    public void setLeftChild(TreeNode left) {
        this.left = left;
        if (left != null) {
            left.root= this;
        }
    }
```

Would the same function `setLeftChild` above be represented like the function below:

```
     void setLeftChild(TreeNode node)
    {
        if(root == null)
        {
            this.root = node;
        }
        else
        {
            this.left = node;
        }
    }
```

- Is the implementation correct? first and 2nd?

  - If not then what is wrong with the 2nd implementation? and vice versa
- What is the difference between first and 2nd implementation?

Comment: no, `node` is not necessarily the same as `this` and it is the `left`'s root that is being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the bottom code is not correct.  In the bottom implementation what you do is you make the left child node actually the parent node of your class.  If the node you are in already is not the root node then the left child is set correctly, but the left child does not get its parent set correctly.

The image below is the result of executing the code on the bottom

[image]

The image below is the result of executing the top block (which is correct)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you did

```
 TreeNode a = new TreeNode (1);
```

At this time a's `left`, `right` and `root` are null

if you did

```
TreeNode b = new TreeNode (b);
a.setLeftChild (b);
```

then now a's `right` and `root` are still null but `left` is `b`

and b's `root` is now `a`

Comment: so which implementation is correct?
And can you tell me working of my first and 2nd method? what happens? and how I am wrong in 1 of them

Comment: as to which implementation is correct depends upon your business logic.  What are you wanting to achieve?  I would say that if you are setting the left of A to be B, then the right of B should be A - eh?

Answer (score -2):

*this* is a reference to current object 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: @sps It doesnt satisfy my question